# How should passwords and usernames be stored in a C#/ASP.NET web app environment using SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-applications, passwords

When storing passwords and usernames in an ASP.NET C# web app how should they be stored?

Should I use a known encryption library function in .NET should I purchase an algorithm?

Should I develop my own which I have been told would be bad if I tried to develop my own as I am not an encryption specialist or encryption developer neither do I have a PHD in math dealing with discrete mathematics.

Should I use a Hash Table and then salt it? Any guidance or technical papers online or Udemy or Youtube video showing how to properly protect and store passwords/Usernames in an ASP.NET MVC C# app with SQL Server would be great! Or if you know right off the bat what should be done to protect this information please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Hashing and salting your passwords - and **DO NOT** try to roll your own - use existing, proven technology!